What's the easiest way to get the speed at the tip of a double pendulum?
Say we have a double pendulum consisting of two rods of lengths $l_1$ and $l_2$, anchored at points $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively (hence $p_2$ is time-variant), where the first rod is at an angle $\theta_1$ from the vertical, and the second rod is at an angle $\theta_2$ from the first rod, and the corresponding angular velocities are $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.  Now we want the speed (squared) at the tip of the second rod to plug into the Lagrangian.  If we do everything in Cartesian coordinates, we have to get the position vector at the tip in terms of both angles, differentiate it to get velocity, and apply Pythagoras to get speed squared.  The algebra turns out to be very tedious and redundant.
An easier way is to note that the tip has a separate velocity component due to each angle, that is,
$$\vec v = \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\theta_1}\omega_1 + \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\theta_2}\omega_2 \equiv \vec v_1 + \vec v_2$$
where $\vec r$ and $\vec v$ are the position and velocity of the tip relative to the anchor.  These two terms are really just the tangential velocities of the circular motions of the tip about $p_1$ and $p_2$, and thus have magnitudes of $r\omega_1$ and $l_2\omega_2$, with $r$ the magnitude of $\vec r$.  Furthermore, as each velocity is perpendicular to its corresponding radius, the angle between them is the same as that between $\vec r$ and the second rod, which we can call $\alpha$.  Given all this, we apply the law of cosines three times: once on the triangle consisting of $l_1$, $l_2$, and $r$ to find $r$, again on the same triangle to find $\cos{\alpha}$, and finally on the triangle represented by the equation $\vec v_1 + \vec v_2 = \vec v$ to get $v^2$, since the angle there is $\pi-\alpha$.
This seems algebraically much neater, but I still have the impression there's a bit of redundancy here; it left me with the feeling there should be an even simpler, more elegant approach, so I'm reaching out to see if anyone has one.

In my opinion, the easiest way to deal with this is to use polar unit vectors. Each mass is being described in its own set of polar coordinates, so in general $\hat \theta_1 \neq \hat \theta_2$, where $\hat \theta_1$ and $\hat \theta_2$ correspond to the unit vectors for each mass that point in the directions that each mass would need to move from their current positions in order to increase their angles. In fact, based on your definition of $\theta_2$ being the angle of rod 2 relative to rod 1, we have $\hat \theta_1 \cdot \hat \theta_2 = \cos \theta_2$. Your velocity of mass 2 can very simply be written as follows.
$$\vec v = l_1 \dot \theta_1 \hat \theta_1 + l_2 (\dot \theta_1 + \dot \theta_2) \hat \theta_2$$
Use a dot product and some distribution in order to obtain $v^2$ (this is equivalent to using the law of cosines once).
$$v^2 = \vec v \cdot \vec v = l_1^2 \dot \theta_1^2 + l_2^2 \dot (\dot \theta_1 + \dot \theta_2)^2 + 2 l_1 l_2 \dot \theta_1 (\dot \theta_1 + \dot \theta_2) \cos \theta_2$$
If this derivation feels too concise for comfort, you may find this derivation, which uses Cartesian coordinates, more comfortable. The result is ultimately the same, but keep in mind that they define $\theta_2$ differently than we do here.

Bingo, that's it!  However, one important correction: your original equation for $\vec v$ actually relies on $\theta_2$ being the absolute angle of rod 2, not its angle relative to rod 1.  This is because it's a sum of relative velocities, but the rotational velocity of the tip relative to the joint is based on $\theta_1 + \theta_2$, not just $\theta_2$.  But that's fine because we can just replace $\dot{\theta_2}$ with $\dot{\theta_1} + \dot{\theta_2}$ everywhere and then your result matches mine.  If you can make that change then I'll definitely accept this answer.

Ah, good point! :) I will make that edit.
